# regex, save a value in a array

Tags: php, regex, callback

In a string each time there is a word with a # I want to save the word in an array, here my code :

```
<?php
function tag($matches)
{
    $hash_tag = array();
    $hash_tag[]=$matches[1];
    return '<strong>' . $matches[1] . '</strong>';
}
$test = 'this is a #test1 #test2 #test3 #test4 #test5 #test6';
$regex = "#(\#.+)#";
$test = preg_replace_callback($regex, "tag", $test);
echo $test;
?>
```

But I don't know how to put each new word in a new cell of the array $hash_tag
and i really need help on this one

Comment: You should really read about "[variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)". Then you will be able to rewrite your code yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see you want to do 2 things at the same time

- Replace the words with strong tag
- Get all the words ans use later

You can try

```
$hash_tag = array();
$tag = function ($matches) use(&$hash_tag) {
    $hash_tag[] = $matches[1];
    return '<strong>' . $matches[1] . '</strong>';
};

$test = 'this is a #test1 #test2 #test3 #test4 #test5 #test6';
$regex = "/(\#[0-9a-z]+)/i";
$test = preg_replace_callback($regex, $tag, $test);
echo $test;
var_dump($hash_tag); <------ all words now in this array
```

**Output**

this is a **#test1** **#test2** **#test3** **#test4** **#test5** **#test6**

```
array (size=6)
  0 => string '#test1' (length=6)
  1 => string '#test2' (length=6)
  2 => string '#test3' (length=6)
  3 => string '#test4' (length=6)
  4 => string '#test5' (length=6)
  5 => string '#test6' (length=6)
```

Comment: thanks a lot for this answeer, please if you have 30s, can you explain me what are "&" and "use"?? anyway thanks a lot for your answer @Baba

Comment: `&` is a Reference Please see [What References Do](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php) and The `use` keyword allows you to introduce local variables into the local scope of an anonymous function .. that is why i can use `$hash_tag` without having to use globals

Answer (score 1):

try to use [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)()

after get all matches in one array you can make loop through it.

Answer (score 0):

Well here's the regex: `/\#[a-zA-Z0-9]*/`

In PHP, I beleive that you would use `preg_match_all('/\#[a-zA-Z0-9]*/', string)`

Answer (score 0):

Use `preg_match_all()` and loop through all matches:

```
<?php
$test = 'this is a #test1 #test2 #test3 #test4 #test5 #test6';
$regex = "(\#[^#]+?)";
preg_match_all($regex, $test, $hash_tag);
foreach ($hash_tag as $match) {
    echo '<strong>' . $match . '</strong>';
}
?>
```